Polars selector for columns of dtype pl.List
In the polars documentation regarding selectors, there are many examples for selecting columns based on their dtypes. I am missing pl.List
How can I quickly select all columns of type pl.List within a pl.DataFrame?

ref: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/15489

if you know they type of the lists (for example pl.Int64), you can do df.select(cs.by_dtype(pl.List(pl.Int64)))

At the moment it's not possible to select all lists with selectors, but if you have lists of specific type, you can do it:
df.select(cs.by_dtype(pl.List(pl.Int64))) 

